# How to add another row in a custom form?

Tags: 7, theming

I have created a custom form in Drupal 7 custom module. In this situation I face a problem to **add another row** functionality.

In this picture I need to add multiple row as I need:

[image]

Any help to create this functionality?

**UPDATED:**

**my template.php file-**

```
function mytheme_admin_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
$items['mgms_order_form'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'template' => 'mgms_order_template_page',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/tpl',
);

return $items;
}
```

**my custom form fields-**

```
function mgms_order_form($form, &$form_state, $id){

if(isset($id) && is_numeric($id)){
$result = db_select('fabrication_info', 'fi')
    ->fields('fi')
    ->condition('id', $id)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();

$form_state['values']['fs_fabric'] = $result['fs_fabric'];
$form_state['values']['fs_composition'] = $result['fs_composition'];
$form_state['values']['fs_gsm'] = $result['fs_gsm'];
$form_state['values']['fs_supplier'] = $result['fs_supplier'];
$form_state['values']['fs_remarks'] = $result['fs_remarks'];
}

$form = array();

$form['#attributes']['enctype'] = "multipart/form-data";

//Fabrication Sheet
$form['fs_fabric'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  '#title' => 'Fabric',
  '#size' => 20,
  '#maxlength' => 55,
  '#description' => '',
  '#default_value' => (isset($form_state['values']['fs_fabric'])) ? $form_state['values']['fs_fabric'] : '',
);
$form['fs_composition'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  '#title' => 'Composition',
  '#size' => 20,
  '#maxlength' => 555,
  '#description' => '',
  '#default_value' => (isset($form_state['values']['fs_composition'])) ? $form_state['values']['fs_composition'] : '',
);
$form['fs_gsm'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  '#title' => 'GSM/Construction',
  '#size' => 20,
  '#maxlength' => 55,
  '#description' => '',
  '#default_value' => (isset($form_state['values']['fs_gsm'])) ? $form_state['values']['fs_gsm'] : '',
);
$form['fs_supplier'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  '#title' => 'Supplier',
  '#size' => 20,
  '#maxlength' => 55,
  '#description' => '',
  '#default_value' => (isset($form_state['values']['fs_supplier'])) ? $form_state['values']['fs_supplier'] : '',
);
$form['fs_remarks'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  '#title' => 'Remarks',
  '#size' => 20,
  '#maxlength' => 255,
  '#description' => '',
  '#default_value' => (isset($form_state['values']['fs_remarks'])) ? $form_state['values']['fs_remarks'] : '',
);


if(isset($id) && is_numeric($id)){
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Update Order'),
);
} else {
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Create Order'),
);
}

return $form;

}
```

**my mgms_order_template_page file-**

```
<div id="mgms-order-action-page" class="action-pages">
<div class="moap-inner clearfix">
    <form id="moap-form">

        <table class="fabrication-sheet">
            <thead>
            <tr><th colspan="7">Fabrication Sheet</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="serial">SL</th>
                <th>Fabric</th>
                <th>Composition</th>
                <th>GSM/Construction</th>
                <th>Supplier</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="lbl">#1</td>
                <td class="inp"><?php print render($form['fs_fabric']); ?></td>
                <td class="inp"><?php print render($form['fs_composition']); ?></td>
                <td class="inp"><?php print render($form['fs_gsm']); ?></td>
                <td class="inp"><?php print render($form['fs_supplier']); ?></td>
                <td class="inp"><?php print render($form['fs_remarks']); ?></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7"><button type="button">Add Another Row</button></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </form>
</div>
</div>

<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

**Note***: None of the answers to "***[How to implement "Add another item" for custom forms?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/32152/39516)***" helped to solve my question here ...

Comment: What have you done? What have you tried so far? What code is generating that?

Comment: Hey Kevin, thank you for quick reply. I have create a form in my custom module and for my design purpose I used custom template file for this form by override form theme from theme template.php file. Please wait, I updating my  question.

Comment: I suggest you further improve the part I added to the end of your question, to better explain how your question differs from that linked question ... good luck(

Comment: Where is `$form['#tree'] = TRUE`? Where is the `for` loop? Man you have to make your homework. I'll reflag this question once again as duplicate.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, there's nothing in your code to suggest you've tried any of the solutions so it's not possible to advise any further at the moment. @leymannx's answer in the duplicate is a good approach, I'd recommend that one to start with. But read the links in the other answer too, they'll give you some extra background about what you're actually trying to convince the form API to do