# Custom Form 'Add More' widget for a field

Tags: 8, forms

This seems like something that should be easy to do but I can find any examples.

When adding a field through the UI you can set the cardinality of the field to unlimited which, given a field type like Number, will give an 'Add More' button underneath the field. This button will pull in another instance of the field via ajax.

Given that you can add this functionality in the UI as part of Core there should surely be away to easily add this in via the Form API?

Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement "Add another item" for custom forms?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32152/how-to-implement-add-another-item-for-custom-forms)

Comment: See the [`AjaxAddMore.php`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/blob/8.x-1.x/form_api_example/src/Form/AjaxAddMore.php) example. There is not prebuilt widget for this. You have to implement it yourself.